# Strange rebooting on RPi 3

Tags: pi-3

I got an RPi 3 up and running yesterday and turned it on. It seemed to work fine, but after a while it randomly rebooted, I don't believe I caused it to happen. So  I didn't think much of it until it happened again, and then again awhile later.

I'm not sure what could be causing this, though I believe the SD card needs to be changed slightly for use in the 3. I don't know why that would affect it.

Would the card affect it? If not what would be doing this?

Comment: The standard guess is that it's a power issue. The RPi 3 is a hungry, hungry hippo, and it gets unhappy if you don't feed it properly. Do the logs indicate anything useful?

Comment: Where are the logs?

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` would be the best place to start, normally.

Comment: ... on any reasonable linux `journalctl` will be your friend.

Comment: What does `/lib/udev/mtp-probe` do? It looks like whatever the problem was it started there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this happen with my Raspberry PI 3. My pi was drawing too much power when under heavy load, crashing and then restarting.Since the PI 3 uses around 1.34 amps under max stress, my 2.0 USB port was not powerful enough to run some applications i requested from it and this could be what you are experiencing.

A few things you could do to test this could be to leave your pi idling. If it still crashes then it is most likely an OS problem and a fresh install/upgrade should resolve any issues. But if this still does not fix the problem then you are not supplying it with enough power.

Power Usage Reference: https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs

Answer (score 5):

My RPi 3 restarted like this as well.

I was using my older power supply which had 5v/2 amps or something similar. I switched to a newer power supply which had 5.25v/2.4 amps and the problem went away. I think that the new quad core just uses a little more power.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was this:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=122601

So after commenting out this chunk of `/etc/rsyslog.conf` the Pi is not doing unexpected rebootings anymore (which caused the `broken pipe` ssh freeze):

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
       news.err;\
       *.=debug;*.=info;\
       *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's a low voltage issue...try another power adapter...(i used samsung> 5v - 1.55A and it works)

Comment: This adds little to the existing answers. And provides no pertinent facts.

Answer (score 0):

The power needed for the program you were using at the moment were it rebooted was high . You mustn't use or install a program (or a game) if your pi's conditions doesn't fit in the system compatibilities . Or you must have set a specific time in the terminal to reboot. Like you said , the SD card can get damaged by going corrupted and finally you will need to install Raspbian OS again .